# Is it possible to add native sdks to flutter app and create a bridge between flutter app and a native SDK?

Tags: flutter, sdk

I have an android SDK in java and IOS SDK in objective-c developed by a third party, unfortunately they do not have a flutter plugin which could make things a lot easier. I am wondering if it is possible to integrate the native sdks into flutter app and call the native sdk's functions from flutter using dart?

I also found this link that talks about `flutter channel` : https://medium.com/@pahlevikun/bridging-between-dart-and-native-code-with-flutter-channel-for-communicate-each-other-7c736929ee42

Comment: yes `MethodChannel` is what you need: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: @pskink thank you! just wanted some re-assurance from someone :), now i can go ahed and dive deep into it

Comment: good luck then ;-)